# Countable structure with qe and not ultrahomogeneous

Tags: model-theory

Here: [The connection between quantifier elimination, $\omega$-categorical and ultrahomogenous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853554/the-connection-between-quantifier-elimination-omega-categorical-and-ultrahom)

I gave an example of an uncountable structure, that is not ultrahomogeneous but has quantifier elimination. 
Now I am looking for a countable (relational) structure with qe but not ultrahomog. Of course the structure can't be $\omega$-categorical. And we need an infinite signature.

I think I have to look for a structure, where I can find two n-tuples $\bar{a} \bar{b}$, that have the same type, but there is no automorphism carrying $\bar{a}$ to $\bar{b}$. (And then I add a new predicate to the language for each formula that is valid to get qe).
But I don't know how to construct such structure. Maybe you could help.. Thank you!!

Comment: Hint: If two elements have the same type, but they aren't conjugate via an automorphism, then they must differ in a way that isn't expressible by any first-order formula. Some go-to properties that can't be expressed in first-order: 1) First-order formulas can't distinguish between "arbitrarily large and finite" and "infinite". 2) First-order formulas can't express the existence of some element satisfying some (non-isolated) type.

Comment: How about the following: We use the ordered natural numbers $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ and add a disjunct copy of the ordered integers $(\mathbb{Z}',\leq')$ on top. That means: $A= \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{Z}'$ and $\mathbb{N} \cap \mathbb{Z}' = \emptyset$. The signature $L$ consists of one binary relationsymbol $\leq^* := \leq \cup \leq' \cup (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}')$ The type $p(x):= \lbrace n \leq x | n \in \mathbb{N}\rbrace$ is not isolated in $A$ (as it is not isolated in the elementary substructure $\mathbb{N}$), but $A \models p(0')$ ($0' \in \mathbb{Z}'$)

Comment: @Vicky: what would be your $\overline a$ and $\overline b$ here?

Comment: Good question.. The two zeros?  ($0^' \in \mathbb{Z}'$ and $0 \in \mathbb{N}$)

Comment: No, they don't have the same type.. Maybe I have to add another disjunct copy of the ordered naturals next to my structure and then my two tuples are the two natural zeros?

Comment: @Vicky: not quite, the second "natural zero" would still have an infinite number of predecessors in $<$, whereas the first one is the least element. But you are almost done: consider $\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z$ with binary predicates $x<y+p$ for all $p\in\mathbb Z$, where the interpretation is the natural one: inside each copy it works as you would expect, and if $x$ is in the first copy and $y$ in the second, $x<y+p$ for all $p\in\mathbb Z$. (I added all those predicates so that the theory has qe, but you could also only take $<$ and add predicates after as you wanted to do.)

Comment: I am a bit confused and mix your and my example in my head..! So I don't quite understand how I can only take < (and add predicates after). What if I take the structure as described in my first comment and copy it to get a structure A'. Don't the two zeroes from Z′ and (lets call it) Z′′ have the same type?

Comment: @Vicky: so the order in your structure would be $\mathbb N+\mathbb Z'+\mathbb N'+\mathbb Z''$? This indeed works as you want!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I will post it as an answer tomorrow! :-)

Comment: I just want to jump in and point out that Vicky's original suggestion "Maybe I have to add another disjunct copy of the ordered naturals next to my structure and then my two tuples are the two natural zeros?" works, if I'm interpreting it correctly. In the partial order $(\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}) \sqcup \mathbb{N}$ (*not* the linear order $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{N}$), the zeros of the two copies of the naturals have the same type.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: oh, of course, I misinterpreted the comment and thought the order was linear. Thank you for setting me straight!

Comment: Thank you Alex! Next time I should just post better comments, that can't be misinterpreted..

Answer (score 2):

(I finally post my comment as an answer. I encourage you to continue working on your own counterexample, post it and accept it, so that you can make your own intuition on what happens.)

Let us consider the structure whose domain is $\mathbb Z \times\{0,1\}$, with a countable number of binary relation symbols $<_p$ ($p\in\mathbb Z$) whose interpretation in the structure is $\{((a,0),(b,0))\mid a<b+p\}\cup\{((a,1),(b,1))\mid a<b+p\}\cup\{((a,0),(b,1))\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$.

This structure has quantifier elimination, and $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have the same type (because there is only one $1$-type). However, an automorphism $\alpha$ of this structure maps any $(a,1)$ to  a $(b,1)$ in the same copy, for we have $(0,0)<_p (a,1)$ for all $p\in\mathbb Z$, so that $\alpha(0,0) <_p \alpha(a,1)$ for all $p\in\mathbb Z$ and this is only possible if $\alpha(a,1)\in\mathbb Z\times\{1\}$. Thus no automorphism maps $(0,1)$ to $(0,0)$, and the structure is not homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two disjunct copies of the ordered natural numbers $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ and $(\mathbb{N^\star}, \leq^\star)$. Then we add a disjunct copy of the ordered integers $(\mathbb{Z}', \leq ')$ on top of $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$.

So the domain of our structure $\mathcal{A}$ is: $A= \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N}^\star \cup \mathbb{Z}'$, with $\mathbb{N} \cap \mathbb{N}^\star = \mathbb{Z}' \cap \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}' \cap \mathbb{N}^\star = \emptyset$ and the signature $L$ consists of one binary relation symbol $R := \leq^\star \cup \leq^*$, whereas $\leq^* := \leq \cup \leq' \cup (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z'})$.

Now we know, that the type $p(x)= \lbrace R(n,x) x| n\in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ is not realised in ($\mathbb{N}, \leq$), but it is realised in $\mathcal{A}$ (because: $ \mathcal{A} \models p(0')$ for $0' \in \mathbb{Z'}$). And we know, that $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$. It follows that $p(x)$ can't be isolated in $\mathcal{A}$ as isolated types are realised in elementary substructures.

The two elements $0^\star \in \mathbb{N}^\star$ and $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ have the same type (as the theories $Th(\mathbb{N^\star}, R)$ and $Th(\mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{Z'}, R)$ are elementary equivalent) but because of the non-isolated type $p(x)$ there is no automorphism $f$ with $f(0) = 0^\star$. Hence $\mathcal{A}$ is not ultrahomogenous.

To get quantifier elimination we finally add for each formula $\varphi$ in n free variables with $\mathcal{A} \models \varphi$ an $n$-ary relationsymbol to the signature.

Comment: The language should just be a *single* binary relation symbol $\leq = \leq^\star \cup \leq^*$. Otherwise, $0^\star$ and $0$ will have different types ($\mathcal{A}\models \exists y\, 0^\star \leq^\star y$ but $\mathcal{A}\models \lnot \exists y\, 0 \leq^\star y$).

Comment: Note that in your setup the statement "$(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$" doesn't make sense, because they have different signatures. Finally, your argument using Ryll-Nardzewski uses the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ has a finite signature. But $\mathcal{A}$ doesn't yet have QE. Once you Morleyize (by the way, it doesn't suffice to add a *unary* relation symbol for each formula - for each formula in $n$ free variables, you need to add an $n$-ary relation symbol), the signature will no longer be finite, and the Ryll-Nardzewski argument doesn't apply.